# What is the difference between Crucible and Vanguard gear?

Tags: destiny

Destiny can be played in one of two ways, story mode which yields vanguard marks, or pvp which yields crucible marks. It's possible to use either of those currencies to buy related gear. Is there any significant different between the gear that costs crucible marks or the kind that costs vanguard marks? Is the crucible gear somehow better for pvp?

Comment: There seems to be about the same type of gear, and contrary to other games, items that you earn from PvP bonuses doesn't have any special meaning in PvP. For instance, Rift required you to use PvP gear, otherwise it would "normalize" all your normal PvE gear to base PvP gear. If you wanted to upgrade it, and perhaps add enchantments (or what Rift called those things), you needed to buy PvP gear specifically. In Destiny, you purchase the gear from the PvP vendor, using a currency you earned by playing PvP, but other than that, there seems to be no more special treatment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overall there is not any significant difference between the gear from the vanguard vendor, the crucible vendor, and the faction vendors.

It's more about what kind of build you want to play and what kind of weapons you're comfortable with.

Also, many top level items come from things outside of the crucible and vanguard economies, such as rewards from raids, nightfall strikes, the Queen mission, engram drops, and purchases from Xur.

Comment: It should be noted that the armor from the faction vendors each focus on a different combination of 2 of the 3 [Player Attributes](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Attribute)

Answer (score 2):

If you're still curious, the Crucible gear is slightly better for PvP - but mostly in terms of the "perks" you unlock. EG, compare the PvP hand cannon (http://www.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Lord_High_Fixer) to the PvE one (http://www.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/The_Devil_You_Know). The have the same attack, and some slight variations on other stats, but for the most part are similar. The big differences are in their perks - IE, being able to view your radar while ADS (Third Eye) is more useful in PvP, whereas something like bonus damage after a kill (Crowd Control) will proc more in a PvE setting.

Answer (score 0):

Items bought from either vendor can be used in either PvP or PvE. There are no restrictions on crucible items being used in PvE. The only diffrence is where the marks and reputation comes from to purchase the items.